# nslcd lookup failed: No results returned

Tags: authentication, ldap

I'd like to authenticate my users with my LDAP Directory.
I've configured nslcd to do it, but it fails.
nslcd debug mode indicates this :

> nslcd: [b0dc51]  DEBUG:
>   ldap_simple_bind_s("uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr","***")
>   (uri="ldap://net.ch-havre.fr") nslcd: [b0dc51]  DEBUG:
>   ldap_result(): end of results (0 total) nslcd: [b0dc51] 
>   uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr: lookup failed: No results
>   returned
>
> getent passwd seb -> OK getent shadow seb -> OK

Thanks you for answering.
My search base is defined in nslcd.conf as :

```
uid nslcd
gid ldap
ldap_version 3
binddn cn=UnixBind,dc=Unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
bindpw XXXXXX
base   group  ou=Group,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
base   passwd ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
base   shadow ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
ssl no
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
uri ldap://net.ch-havre.fr
base dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
```

Is there something wrong ?

This is the debug mode output :

```
nslcd: [b71efb] DEBUG: connection from pid=20820 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [b71efb] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=seb))")
nslcd: [b71efb] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
nslcd: [b71efb] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [e2a9e3] DEBUG: connection from pid=20820 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [e2a9e3] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=seb))")
nslcd: [e2a9e3] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
nslcd: [e2a9e3] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [45e146] DEBUG: connection from pid=20820 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [45e146] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=seb))")
nslcd: [45e146] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
nslcd: [45e146] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [5f007c] DEBUG: connection from pid=20820 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [5f007c] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=seb))")
nslcd: [5f007c] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
nslcd: [5f007c] <passwd="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [d062c2] DEBUG: connection from pid=20820 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: nslcd_pam_authc("seb","sshd","***")
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=seb))")
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr", filter="(objectClass=*)")
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://net.ch-havre.fr)
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr","***") (uri="ldap://net.ch-havre.fr")
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr: lookup failed: No results returned
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr", filter="(&(objectClass=shadowAccount)(uid=seb))")
nslcd: [d062c2] <authc="seb"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr
```

Sebastien

Comment: What is in your nslcd.conf ?

Comment: I suggest you try to use one single _global_ search base (comment out MAP-specific bases) and see if it changes anything : 
`base      dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr`

Comment: It does work as well.

Comment: I've added the debug mode output in my question.

Comment: Bindings and search base are ok because 'seb' entry is found, but simple authentication with `ldap_simple_bind_s()` fails. Since we know seb entry's dn is correct, you issue might come from elsewhere. Check your ACLs. Also I see a call to `ldap_set_rebind_proc()`, so it appears your application needs to bind to another server in order to follow a referral or search continuation reference, is this really needed ? First, I would try to manually bind with seb's credentials to see if it works with/without referals.

Comment: How could I do that ?

Comment: ldapsearch ldapsearch -D "uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr" -w abc -p 389 -h net.ch-havre.fr -b "dc=ch-havre,dc=fr                     " -s sub "(objectclass=*)"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=ch-havre,dc=fr> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ldapsearch (objectclass=*)
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

Comment: Credentials seems ok otherwise it would throw an authentication error,don't be confuse with the "result: 0" part, you should see the result using a 'base' scope by setting the binddn as basedn : `ldapsearch -H ldap://net.ch-havre.fr -D 'uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr' -w abc -s base -b 'uid=seb,ou=Users,dc=unix,dc=ch-havre,dc=fr'`.

Comment: So ? I'm lost. what should I do now ?

Comment: Your configuration appears to be fine for the binding and the lookup parts (ldap related settings are ok), so I would suspect a wrong mapping for userPassword or something like that.. How do you test the authentication of your users ?

Comment: From another server (RHEL 6), I can authenticate with "seb" and it's OK.

Comment: But from RHEL 7, this server, I can't...

Comment: I'm sure you did already but I'd check nslcd.conf on the 2 servers, use explicit settings as much you can (defaults are implicit but they may differ from one RHEL/nlscd version to another) especially for mappings, check `userPassword` map. Also I'd compare the other nss and pam settings. While you keep digging, consider disabling SELinux to avoid any sec policy mismatch that could break authentication (e.g. SELinux might prevent the creation/auto-mount of the user's homeDirectory). Use `authconfig` or `authconfig-tui` instead of editing config manually if you can. Sorry, no more ideas...